# Posición de Barra de Progreso

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, progressbar

he creado una barra de progreso pero veo que por defecto aparece en horizontal
¿Se puede cambiar la barra de progreso de jQuery UI a vertical?

Comment: Añade tu código por favor

Comment: En sí sólo es un div con un id="progressbar" y el js le doy la propiedad de barra de progreso

$('progressbar').progressbar({
Así ya se crea, y aqui dentro van valores, llegué a tener la duda de si aquí iría alguna propiedad que le dé la orientación de vertical pero no, jeje
});

Comment: Una buena forma de es utilizando transform: rotate(90deg);
Con esta propiedad podrás rotar la div 90 grados desde su esquina inferior izquierda.
Suerte!

Answer (score 0):

Existe [este plugin](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jquery-progressbarvertical/), pero no lo he usado y no sé si pueda adaptarse a lo que ud está buscando.

También, ud podría crearlo usando HTML & CSS. Realice este [demo funcional](http://jsfiddle.net/VNjVv/) donde agregué un JqueryUi Slider control para mirar el estado del progressBar. Aquí esta el código básico (sólo para la barra)

HTML

```
<div class="progressbar">
 <span class="progressbar-value">
  <em class="progressbar-cover"></em>
 </span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.progressbar {
   width: 25px;
   height: 215px;
   position: relative;
   background: transparent url(http://i48.tinypic.com/290tvnk.png) no-repeat;
}
.progressbar-value {
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   margin: 0;
   border: 0;
   width: 15px;
   height: 200px;
   top: 7px;
   left: 5px;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-indent: -30px;
   background: #0f0 url(http://i45.tinypic.com/minc5g.png) center center;
}
.progressbar-cover {
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   width: 15px;
   height: 200px;
   border: 0;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0%;
   background: transparent url(http://i49.tinypic.com/1zwge3s.png) repeat-x 0 0;
}
```

[Tomado de](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974212/is-there-anyway-to-have-jquery-ui-progress-bar-show-up-vertical)